# Sincronizar openldap entero en modo multi-master

Tags: openldap

Estoy intentando crear una replica de openldap en modo multi-master con 3 nodos.
Actualmente tengo sincronizado la siguiente configuración:

```
dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config
changetype: modify
add:
   olcSyncRepl
olcSyncRepl:
   rid=001
   provider=ldap://open-ldap-01
   binddn="cn=config"
   bindmethod=simple
   credentials=xxxxxx
   searchbase="cn=config"
   type=refreshAndPersist
   retry="5 5 300 5"
   timeout=1
olcSyncRepl:
   rid=002
   provider=ldap://open-ldap-02
   binddn="cn=config"
   bindmethod=simple
   credentials=xxxxxx
   searchbase="cn=config"
   type=refreshAndPersist
   retry="5 5 300 5"
   timeout=1
olcSyncRepl:
   rid=003
   provider=ldap://open-ldap-03
   binddn="cn=config"
   bindmethod=simple
   credentials=xxxxxx
   searchbase="cn=config"
   type=refreshAndPersist
   retry="5 5 300 5"
   timeout=1
-
add: olcMirrorMode
olcMirrorMode: TRUE
EOF

ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f configrep.ldif
```

Como puedo hacer para que se sincronicen una nueva OU? Podria sincronizar todo el Openldap al completo?

Gracias!